# Formatting a URL into a Cell using VBA

Tags: vba

I think this is easy to do but after about 3 hours of Google fu I can't get an answer that works.

I have a userform that asks for a ticket number then puts that ticket number in a cell, I want it to be a hyperlink.

so cell A7 would be "1234567890"
and the hyperlink would be "www.ticketsyustem.com/ticketID1234567890"

is there a way to have this put in to the cell from the user form

Thanks

Comment: Have you try to use the function concatenate?

Comment: Yep no luck I the URL not the text and its not a hyperlink

Comment: You can use the `HYPERLINK()` function for this

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
    Dim hlink As String
'    hlink = "www.ticketsystem.com/ticketID" & tb.Text
    hlink = "www.ticketsystem.com/ticketID"
    Range("A1").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("A1"), Address:=hlink, TextToDisplay:=tb.Text
```

Where `tb.Text` is the reference to your userform textbox that captures the ticketID

Comment: I get Compile Error: Duplicate declaration in current scope